# ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property visible not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
function item_back_click(evt:Event):void {
     var back:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.currentTarget);
     var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(MovieClip(back.parent).data.@link);
     var listnumber = ("listbox" + MovieClip(back.parent).data.@link);
     trace(listnumber);
     if (listnumber.visible == false) listnumber.visible = true;
}
```

`trace(listnumber);` displays `listbox1`

but

```
if (listnumber.visible == false) listnumber.visible = true;
```

Gives error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property visible not found on String and there is no default value.
    at listbox_fla::listbox_1/item_back_click()
```

Why is this?

and this works well:

```
if (listbox1.visible == false) listbox1.visible = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"listBox1" is a string not a variable. So basically you are trying to access the visible property of a string which doesn't exist.

```
"listBox1".visible = true;  // error
```

Try :

```
this[listnumber].visible = true;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot Baris, that was quick and just what i needed. Is there any way to set visible to False when the item name is ***not*** listnumber?

Comment: if( listnumber != "listBox1") 
  this[listnumber].visible = false;
else
  this[listnumber].visible = true;